# gimp 2.10.32-0build7 hangs at querying new plug ins on ubuntu 22.04.1 lts

Tags: gimp

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 lts and now GIMP will not launch all the way.
It hangs on querying new plug ins.
On the previous version of Ubuntu I didn't have a problem with GIMP it worked with no issues.

Comment: I did perform updates for Ubuntu and it did load all the way but there was a notification about an internal error from the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Can you reinstall GIMP.  Working fine here on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: "It hangs on querying new plug ins" - then wouldn't the first suspect be a plugin?

Comment: Gimp installed before update to 22.04? Yes -> better reinstall gimp.